# JS: Resolve a Formula for x

Tags: javascript, symbolic-math

I have a formula with several components, let's say `w = x * y / z^2 + c`. Now I have an input-field for each variable. My goal is, to calculate the missing one as soon, as all the others were entered. Difficulty is, that you can choose which fields you fill and which you want to leave free.

The *easy* (naive) way would of course be to resolve it for each variable by hand, detect the missing var, and have seperate js functions for each case. But I even have linked formulas (like x in the above formula is `x = a + b`, too) as well and the options are almost infinitive. Is there any option in JS to *solve* a formula by a specified variable? I could then replace each variable string with the assigned value and then `eval` the string.

First I thought [Nerdamer](http://www.nerdamer.com/documentation) would be the thing, but it turned out that it can only evaluate expressions and can't handle equations.

Is this possible? Any better idea?

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: My actual set of formula is:

```
dR = c * I^2 / A
R = L * dR
P = I * U
DV = R * I
DW = DV * I
```

It's for calculating losses in a cable due to ohm's resistance. Each Variable has a corresponding input field.

Comment: What is your exact formula? You'll need to rewrite to formula to have one with each of the variables on the left.

Comment: You can try parsing the formula to an abstract syntax tree, then you can do transformations on the AST relatively easily in order to express one particular variable using the others.

Comment: @SZenC That's what my naive solution was. For big sets of formula it's very tiresome and prone to be flawed.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Can you tell me a little more? Some link for some information?

Comment: @3244611user well, I don't have any specific code to point you to… but here's the idea: once you have an AST, you can start traversing a tree and building a new one by applying the inverse of the operations. If your starting AST is something like `x = y * 2 + z`, and say you want to express `y`, then you do a depth-first traversal on the original one to transform it into `x - z = y * 2` first (the inverse of addition is subtraction), then `(x - z) / 2 = y`. it should be a pretty straightforward algorithm.

Comment: @3244611user, there are in essence two solutions to your problem, 1.) Rewrite all of your equations, or 2.) Write a massively complex JS-library for this purpose.

Comment: @SZenC So there is no available?

Comment: Maybe in PHP and then via AJAX? Or any other shell-based script?

Comment: Nope, there's nothing available to do so. I'm not saying it doesn't exists, but I'm not aware of it. BTW, PHP and other scripts do not have this function natively.

Comment: I know that this is an old question but have you managed to solve it? If no, I've noticed that you have more unknowns than you have equations. Do you have more equations by any chance?

Comment: No unfortunately not. As explained in the question, I don't always need to resolve all variables (e.g. if I have y=x² and x=a+b and the user enters y=4 I would only like to have x=2).

Comment: I know that python has a few symbolic solving packages and of course stuff like mathematica and wolfram alpha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution can be built for finding "R" using [nerdamer](https://github.com/jiggzson/nerdamer). The logic can be extended to solve for the remaining variables. Do keep in mind that the current limitation is that nerdamer can currently only solve up to cubic functions algebraically. Higher order functions will be solved numerically.

```js
//You can then take care of the non linear containing I. I is quadratic
var dR = nerdamer('R=L*dR').solveFor('dR');
var I = nerdamer('dR=c*I^2/A').sub('dR', dR).solveFor('I');
//You can first start by reducing the first few equations since they are linear and you can solve them as a linear system
var solutions = nerdamer.solveEquations(['P = I * U', 'DV = R * I', 'DW = DV * I'], ['I', 'DW', 'P']);
//the solutions come back as an array arrays in the form of [variable, value]
//you can see what they look like. In your case all your solutions will be in terns of DV & U since these are the only actual knowns
//You can see what the solutions look like
solutions.map(function(x) {
    console.log('-'+x[0]+' = '+x[1]);
});
console.log('------------------ R ----------------');
var R = nerdamer.setEquation(I[0], solutions[0][1]).solveFor('R');
//I will have 3 solutions since it's cubic. You can console.log them below
R.map(function(x) {
    console.log('R = '+x.toString());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/nerdamer@latest/nerdamer.core.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/nerdamer@latest/Algebra.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/nerdamer@latest/Calculus.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/nerdamer@latest/Extra.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/nerdamer@latest/Solve.js"></script>
```

Comment: This looks pretty promising. Thank you! I'll have a closer look later!

Comment: No problem. The results from solveEquations are negated but I've updated the answer.  If you find any mistakes please let me know.